# Dynamically Update Element Content after multiplying an integer input with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I request some help with updating the result element content with the product of integer input in the text field with a pre-defined variable.
What i wanted to achieve is the content of the element with id="result" to be updated automatically, i want to achieve this using jquery:

Below is my code, thanks in advance.

```js
<script>
    function updateresult(){
        var operand1 = parseFloat($('slide').val()) || 1;
     var operand2 = 25;
     var produt;
     produt = operand1 * operand2;
     $('#result').html(product);
    }
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>  
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>    
      <div id="text">
        Write to change:<input id="slide" type="text"  onchange="updateText()" />
      </div>
      <div >Total is: <span id="result"></span></div>
      <br/>
    </body>    
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup event of textbox in jquery.

```
$("#slide").keyup(function(e){
     var operand1 = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 1;
    var operand2 = 25;
    var result = operand1 * operand2;
$("#result").html(result);
});
```

[Working Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/0metpajo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things:

- your function is named `updateresult()` but you call a different function: `onchange="updateText()"`
- Instead of `$('slide')` you need to use an id-selector $('#slide')
- you have a typo in `product`, you sometimes refer to it as `poduct`

The code below fixes all of that

```js
function updateText(){
    var operand1 = parseFloat($('#slide').val()) || 1;
 var operand2 = 25;
 var product;
 product = operand1 * operand2;
 $('#result').text(product);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
    Write to change:<input id="slide" type="text" onchange="updateText()">
</div>
<div >Total is: <span id="result"></span></div>
```

There is one more thing: The `change` event gets fired only when the element loses focus, you may want to add `paste` and `keyup` events by removing the `onchange` attribute and add the following to your javascript

```
$('#slide').on('change keyup paste',updateText);
```

And yet another thing: you're using `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` so this is html5. But there are no self-closing tags in html5, so instead of `<tag />` you should just write `<tag>`